# how to select only one radio button at a time having different name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

**html code:**

```
<div id="localPropList"></div>
<div id="assignedPropList"> </div>
```

**js code:**

```
function    getLocalProposals()
        {  // filling these radio buttons dynamically 

            var htmlStringLocalPro = '<fieldset id="local_proposal_id_div" name ="radioGroup" data-role="controlgroup">';
            for (var k = 0; k < result.rows.length; k++) {
              var localProposal = result.rows.item(k);
            if( !(jQuery.inArray( localProposal.id, arrForQueuePropId ) >=0 ) )
        {var fieldId = 'localPro' + k;
            htmlStringLocalPro += '<input group="1" type="radio" name="local_proposal_id" id="' + fieldId + '" value="' + localProposal.enquiry_no + ',' + localProposal.id + '"/>'
                                          + '<label for="' + fieldId + '" data-iconpos="right">' + localProposal.enquiry_no+'-'+localProposal.caller_name+'</label>';
            }
     htmlStringLocalPro += '</fieldset>';
 }


   function  getAssignedproposals()
      {
     var htmlString = '<fieldset id="assigned_proposal_id_div"  name ="radioGroup" data-role="controlgroup">';
    for (var i = 0;i < obj.Proposal.length; i++) {
          proposalIds += obj.Proposal[i].id + ',';
      if( !(jQuery.inArray( obj.Proposal[i].id, arrForQueuePropId ) >=0 ) ){
                     var fieldId = 'ap' + i;
     htmlString += '<input group="1" type="radio" name="assigned_proposal_id" id="' + fieldId + '" value="' + obj.Proposal[i].enquiry_no + ',' + obj.Proposal[i].id + '"/><label for="' + fieldId + '" data-iconpos="right">' + obj.Proposal[i].enquiry_no + '-' + obj.Proposal[i].caller_name + '-' + obj.Proposal[i].post_code + '</label>';
                      //  htmlString += '<input type="radio" name="local_proposal_id" id="' + fieldId + '" value="' + obj.Proposal[i].enquiry_no + ',' + obj.Proposal[i].id + '"/><label for="' + fieldId + '" data-iconpos="right">' + obj.Proposal[i].enquiry_no + '-' + obj.Proposal[i].caller_name + '-' + obj.Proposal[i].post_code + '</label>';
                        }
                    }
    htmlString += '</fieldset>';}

     $("input:radio[name=local_proposal_id]:checked").each(function () {
       var prop = $(this).val().split(',');
 });
     $("input:radio[name=queue_proposal_id]:checked").each(function () {
           var prop = $(this).val().split(',');
});
```

**i need to select only one radio button at a time if radiobutton having name="assigned_proposal_id"   is selected then it should not allow to select any radio buttons for name="local_proposal_id]"    i cannot assign id different i need to do selection on the basis of name  and i cant assign same name to separate group as well 
please tell me whats the solution**

Comment: its not fulfilling my requirement i dnt want to disable i want : when i select localPropid  RADIO then if anyother radio from queue_proposal_id is checked then it should be unchecked and if queue_proposal_id is checked then all other radio buttons should be unchedked instead of disable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking / Unchecking in jQuery Mobile, you need to use `.prop` to checked or unchecked and then call `.checkboxradio('refresh')`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nLBv6/)**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
  $(document).on('change', '[type=radio]', function (e) {

    // Uncheck radio buttons in #group1 and #group2
    $('#group1 [type=radio]:checked, #group2 [type=radio]:checked').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
    // "OR" to select all radio buttons in DOM
    $('[type=radio]:checked').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');

    // Check clicked radio
    $(this).prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
  });
});
```

Comment: i dnt have any #group2  what is group2 please explain ,     your fiddle code and the code you mentioned here is different

Comment: @user1668447 my demo is general, my answer gives two options. If you want, use the code in demo.

Comment: the code on the demo is working fine thanks A lot but i have done one changes in code here is the updated fiddle  instead of ''pageinit''   i have used    $(document).on('pageshow', function ()          http://jsfiddle.net/fJG96/

Comment: but 'pageinit' is called only once while pageshow is called every time

Comment: @user1668447 you're right. It was meant for demo purposes only.

Comment: please raise flag to my comment

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
if($('input [name="assigned_proposal_id"]').is(':checked')){
    $('input [name="local_proposal_id"]').attr('disabled' , true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input [name="assigned_proposal_id"]').click(function(){
```

`if($('input [name="assigned_proposal_id"]').is(':checked')){
    $('input [name="local_proposal_id"]').attr('disabled' , true)`
}

});

It will work like what hussain told

Answer (score 0):

Here [A FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MNqCV/) for your purpose. It will uncheck all the radio button, then check the one we clicked on.

HTML :

```
<div id="localPropList">
<input name="assigned_proposal_id" type="radio" value="value1-1" />value1-1
<input name="assigned_proposal_id" type="radio" value="value1-2" />value1-2
<input name="assigned_proposal_id" type="radio" value="value1-3" />value1-3
</div>
<br/>
<div id="assignedPropList">
<input name="local_proposal_id" type="radio" value="value2-1" />value2-1
<input name="local_proposal_id" type="radio" value="value2-2" />value2-2
<input name="local_proposal_id" type="radio" value="value2-3" />value2-3
</div>
div selected : <span></span>
```

JQUERY :

```
$('#localPropList input[name="assigned_proposal_id"], #assignedPropList input[name="local_proposal_id"]').change(function(){
    $('#localPropList input[name="assigned_proposal_id"], #assignedPropList input[name="local_proposal_id"]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    $('span').html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: its failed to work in case of dynamic id of radioButtons and its not fulfilling my desired result sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
     Disable Syntax:     
     $('input[name="name_here"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

 Don't go for the hardest thing 
Hussein Nazzal is correct but space matters    
between      input and '[' bracket 

if($('input[name="assigned_proposal_id"]:checked').val() != '')
{
$('input[name="local_proposal_id"]:radio').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MNqCV/2/)

Comment: i dnt want to disable the reamining radio sorry this is not the correct  answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, take into account that according to the selector this change will apply to all RadioButtons in the document with the same class, in this case class="chartIndex":

```
$(".chartIndex").change(function () {        
    $('[type=radio]:checked').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', 'checked');        
});
```

Hope this helps someone. Regards.